# Objective-C get slider value and display it on text box

Tags: objective-c

I got a very simple app. it gets slider value and display it on text box. The interface and implementation is as follow:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HelloWorld : NSObject
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *Tf;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSSliderCell *Sc;

@end


#import "HelloWorld.h"

@implementation HelloWorld
@synthesize Tf;
@synthesize Sc;
- (IBAction)Pressed:(id)sender {
    [Tf setStringValue:@"Hey"];
}
- (IBAction)Scroll:(id)sender {
    [Tf setStringValue: [Sc indexOfTickMarkAtPoint]];
}

@end
```

The UI:

[image]

Problem:
The app crashes when I move the slider.

Comment: what is indexOfTickMarkAtPoint returning ? it sounds like an int ?

Answer (score 1):

`indexOfTickMarkAtPoint` returns NSInteger but `setStringValue:` wants (somewhat obviously) a string.  Look at the documentation for NSString method `stringWithFormat:` for a description of how to do the conversion.

Something like:

```
[Tf setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [Sc indexOfTickMarkAtPoint]]];
```

Comment: I just tried that I got error "instance method - indexoftickmarkatpoint not found (return type default to id)"

Comment: Perhaps I typed its name wrong...?  Anyway, the same method that you were already calling on `Sc`.

Answer (score 1):

Whats happening is its an NSInteger and not a pointer to an Object

```
[Tf setIntegerValue:[Sc indexOfTickMarkAtPoint]];
```